# Pairing-free group based encryption scheme

Tags: pairings, functional-encryption

Can someone explain what is a pairing-free group ? There is encryption schemes, for example [1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/128.pdf), that qualify there proposed construction as pairing-free group. However, they use bilinear group in the setup phase. Therefore, how we can qualify a work as a pairing-free based scheme.

Comment: "However, they use bilinear group in the setup phase." It seemed to me that the setup only uses cyclic groups. Could you point out the exact place?

Comment: See please page 23,  Function-Hiding Inner Product Functional Encryption construction

Comment: A pairing-free group, as the name suggests, is a group (or groups) for which bilinear pairing is not known to exist. The construction in section 5, as far as I understood, does not claim to be in the pairing-free setting.